# How to change the default font size in interactive treemap built using d3treeR and treemap in R?

Tags: r, treemap

I am making interactive multi layered treemaps and exporting them as HTML files -  this is how my code looks like:

```
library(googleVis)  #not really needed, only using the datset "Fruit" in example
library(treemap)
library(d3treeR)

fruitTree <- d3tree(
              treemap(Fruits,
                      index=c("Fruit", "Year"),
                      vSize="Profit",
                      vColor="Fruit"
                     )
                     ,rootname = "Fruit")

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as.widget(fruitTree), "D:/temp/fruit.html")
```

I do not like the default font sizes and I do not find any option to manipulate them (at least for the interactive vizs. when 'treemap' command is used).

This is how the output looks like:

1st layer: [image]

2nd layer, when you click on one of the blocks: 
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Open the resulting file and add for example `<style> text.label {  font-size: 20px !important;  } </style>` right after `<head>`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `htmltools::tags()`:

```
library(htmltools)

browsable(
  tagList(
    tags$head(
      tags$style('text.label{font-size: 20px !important}')
    ),
    d3tree(
      treemap(Fruits,
              index=c("Fruit", "Year"),
              vSize="Profit",
              vColor="Fruit"
      )
      ,rootname = "Fruit")
  )
)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: this post http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2016/9/7/custom-styling-for-htmlwidgets might also be useful.  In addition, there is `tasks` functionality and `htmlwidgets::onRender` to post-process.

Comment: @timelyportfolio Very nice ideas. Please feel free to improve on my answer and include these methods as well !